# Paypal on laravel

Tags: laravel, paypal

I'm trying to implement payment on Laravel using this library: https://github.com/anouarabdsslm/laravel-paypalpayment

But I don't understand to what does the variables `$_ClientId` and `$_ClientSecret` correspond to. I know that i have a Paypal Business Account with my own API ID, password and signature but their format is much more shorter. (the ID is my name+lastname+smth, the password is only 8 caracteres).

Anyone please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $_ClientId and $_ClientSecret correspond to.

You need to create your **application** to have right id and secret, which is done via https://developer.paypal.com Once your app is created you will find these information in app details.

**EDIT**

Check this [tutorial video](https://youtu.be/q5Xb5r4MUB8?t=3m21s) using the same libs and Laravel, and around 3:20 guy is showing exactly what you need to do.